# Converting MySQL query into JPA to get count

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

Here I'm having a SQL query which is working fine to get count from the MySQL database which is as

```
 @Query("SELECT count(is_accepted) as value, post_type, is_accepted from agent_activities where "
+ "YEAR(created_date_time) as year and post_type = 'ticket' " +  "GROUP BY is_accepted")
```

And when I'm trying into Java as JPA query it's not working.

```
public interface AgentActivitiesRepo extends JpaRepository<AgentActivitiesEntity, Long> {
@Query("select new ProductIssuesModel"
        + "(count(data.isAccepted) as acceptCount) "
        + "from data where YEAR(data.createdDate) as :year "
        + "and data.postType = :postType " + "group by data.isAccepted")

public List<ProductIssuesModel> findAgentActivitiesYearly(Long year, String postType);

}
```

Here `ProductIssuesModel` is like:

```
public class ProductIssuesModel {

private Long acceptCount;
private Long rejectCount;
private Long year;
private Long month;
...}
```

By running above query, I face an error as:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: as near line 1, column 137 [select new com.accenture.icoe.fm.model.ProductIssuesModel(count(data.isAccepted) as acceptCount) from data where YEAR(data.createdDate) as :year and data.postType = :postType group by data.isAccepted]
```

Please let me know if you see any error.

Comment: you think 'where YEAR(data.createdDate) = :year' instead of 'where YEAR(data.createdDate) as :year'?

Answer (score 0):

Here , `YEAR(data.createdDate) as :year` is not a condtional expression.

You may be try to do this `YEAR(data.createdDate) = :year`.
And use `@Param` to use parameter in JPQL

```
@Query("select new ProductIssuesModel"
        + "(count(data.isAccepted) as acceptCount) "
        + "from data where YEAR(data.createdDate) = :year "
        + "and data.postType = :postType " + "group by data.isAccepted")
public List<ProductIssuesModel> findAgentActivitiesYearly(@Param("year") Long year, @Param("postType") String postType);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to write a JPQL -

---

1. Indexed Query Parameters

```
@Query("select new ProductIssuesModel"
        + "(count(data.isAccepted) as acceptCount) "
        + "from data where YEAR(data.createdDate) = ?1 "
        + "and data.postType = ?2 " + "group by data.isAccepted")

public List<ProductIssuesModel> findAgentActivitiesYearly(Long year, String postType);
```

The values of the parameters will be bind to the query based on the position/index.

---

2. Named Parameters

```
@Query("select new ProductIssuesModel"
        + "(count(data.isAccepted) as acceptCount) "
        + "from data where YEAR(data.createdDate) = :year "
        + "and data.postType = :postType " + "group by data.isAccepted")

public List<ProductIssuesModel> findAgentActivitiesYearly(@Param("year") Long year, @Param("postType") String postType);
```

In your case, the second approach is applicable.